# How can I prove this properly?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(0)>g'(0)$ then there exists $n>0$ so that $f(x)≥g(x)$ $∀x ∈ [0, n]$.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Comment: I'm guessing it should be true $\forall x\in [0,\frac {1}{n}]$ and not $[0,n]$.

Comment: @Jamal $n$ is never stated to be an integer

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh yeah sorry. My mistake.

Comment: But it is common practice that it does and hence misleading, when it does not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the definition of a limit, noting that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = f'(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, then $h(0)=0$ and $h'(0)\gt0$. Then using the definition of a limit, we know that there is a $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that for every $x \in (0,\epsilon)$ then,
 $$\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}>0.$$